# Can I identify which .js script is altering a specific HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reverse-engineering

I will use the following website as an example:

https://www.webdesignrankings.com/resources/rqrwd/

In this website the value is calculated using a `.js` script stored in the `HTML` itself.

By looking at the source (after pressing `F12`) we can identify the element carrying the calculated value as being
`<span id="added">[calculated value here]</span>`
Since there is only one `.js` file in the source code itself, namely `js/scripts.js` I can infer that the formula is there.

But suppose there were multiple scripts, such as `js/scripts1.js`, `js/scripts2.js` and `js/scripts3.js`. Is there a way to know which of them is actually changing the value of the `<span id="added">[calculated value here]</span>` element?

I am well aware that usually these `.js` files jumble up the code so it's not easily readable, but understanding the code is a separate issue. The idea here is to figure out **which** script carries the code I have to try and understand.

*(Disclaimer: I'm not a HTML/CSS/JS guy, so some of the "technical" language may be wrong. This is for a Python web-scraping project. I hope I managed to get the idea across tho)*

***Edit** from Nicolas' comment: the actual usecase doesn't have an `id` property in the element, as it does in the aforementined example*

Comment: Since your example has an id to it, there is a good chance that it is used to alter the value. You might want to look for string like `#added` or `document.getElementById('added')`

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Nicolas! 
The actual usecase has no id, unfortunately. Maybe I should put that in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bookmark icon for this question is altered by `line 2535 of jquery.min.js:formatted`. The developer tools in Chrome already have what you need. You can ask for a break-point to be triggered whenever there's a modification.

In the case of the bookmark icon here, right-click it and inspect-element.
When I did it, a path element inside an svg is highlighted in the element inspector.
I right-clicked the button element in the inspector, then selected "Break on"->"subtree modifications"

Now I expect a breakpoint to be triggered whenever a child of the button changes, so I click the bookmark button and voila! The breakpoint is triggered and the browser tells me which part of the code updated the image.